# Is there a way to better this PyDF2 code?

Tags: python, python-3.7, pypdf

### importing PyPDF2 library

```
import PyPDF2
```

### opening my files

```
tempor = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('super.pdf', 'rb'))
waa = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('wtr.pdf', 'rb'))
out = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
```

### looping through to extract pages that need to be watermarked

```
for i in range(tempor.getNumPages()):
    paging = tempor.getPage(i)
    paging.mergePage(waa.getPage(0))
    output.addPage(paging)

## writing a new pdf file

    with open('merging_merger.pdf', 'wb') as file_new:
        output.write(file_new)
```